# Multiple Radio Button Validation

Tags: javascript, c#, radio-button

I am creating a web form that contains a table housing radio buttons as options for the user to pick. I have grouped the rows by ID and wish the page to not allow users to continue unless each row has a valid selection. I am having trouble with this as the form posts as long as one group has a selection and doesn't assess all the groups. I have included 2 groups for testing purposes, but my webform will actually contain more. I am very new to C# and JavaScript, but I know that I have an issue that both are using isChecked, but I am sure this is not the only issue. I have used this as a guide https://www.codemahal.com/video/radio-buttons-and-form-validation/

Here is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function isChecked() {
         var checkedITEx = document.getElementById('IT-Ex').checked;
         var checkedITVG = document.getElementById('IT-VG').checked;
         var checkedITGd = document.getElementById('IT-Gd').checked;
         var checkedITAve = document.getElementById('IT-Ave').checked;
         var checkedITPoor = document.getElementById('IT-Poor').checked;

         if (checkedITEx == false && checkedITVG == false && checkedITGd == false && checkedITAve == false && checkedITPoor == false) {
             alert('You need to select a rating for Independent Thinking');
             return false;
         }
         else {
             return true;
         }
     }
     function isChecked() {
         var checkedResEx = document.getElementById('Res-Ex').checked;
         var checkedResVG = document.getElementById('Res-VG').checked;
         var checkedResGd = document.getElementById('Res-Gd').checked;
         var checkedResAve = document.getElementById('Res-Ave').checked;
         var checkedResPoor = document.getElementById('Res-Poor').checked;

         if (checkedResEx == false && checkedResVG == false && checkedResGd == false && checkedResAve == false && checkedResPoor == false) {
             alert('You need to select a rating for Resiliance');
             return false;
         }
         else {
             return true;
         }
     }
 </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" action="Default.aspx" method="get" onsubmit="return isChecked();">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1"></td>
            <td class="auto-style2">Excellent</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">Very Good</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">Good</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">Average</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">Poor</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">Independent Thinking</td>
            <td class="auto-style2"><input type="radio" name="IndThink" value ="Independent Thinking - Excellent" id="IT-Ex"/></td>
            <td class="auto-style2"><input type="radio" name="IndThink" value ="Independent Thinking - Very Good" id="IT-VG"/></td>
            <td class="auto-style2"><input type="radio" name="IndThink" value ="Independent Thinking - Good" id="IT-Gd"/></td>
            <td class="auto-style2"><input type="radio" name="IndThink" value ="Independent Thinking - Average" id="IT-Ave"/></td>
            <td class="auto-style2"><input type="radio" name="IndThink" value ="Independent Thinking - Poor" id="IT-Poor"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">Resiliance</td>
            <td class="auto-style2"><input type="radio" name="Res" value ="Resiliance - Excellent" id="Res-Ex"/></td>
            <td class="auto-style2"><input type="radio" name="Res" value ="Resiliance - Very Good" id="Res-VG"/></td>
            <td class="auto-style2"><input type="radio" name="Res" value ="Resiliance - Good" id="Res-Gd"/></td>
            <td class="auto-style2"><input type="radio" name="Res" value ="Resiliance - Average" id="Res-Ave"/></td>
            <td class="auto-style2"><input type="radio" name="Res" value ="Resiliance - Poor" id="Res-Poor"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>  
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manged to get this to co-operate. Here is the code I eventually went with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function isChecked() 
{
     var checkedITEx = document.getElementById('IT-Ex').checked;
     var checkedITVG = document.getElementById('IT-VG').checked;
     var checkedITGd = document.getElementById('IT-Gd').checked;
     var checkedITAve = document.getElementById('IT-Ave').checked;
     var checkedITPoor = document.getElementById('IT-Poor').checked;

     if (checkedITEx == false && checkedITVG == false && checkedITGd == false && checkedITAve == false && checkedITPoor == false)
    {
        alert('You need to select a rating for Independent Thinking');
         return false;
     }
     else 
    {
                var checkedResEx = document.getElementById('Res-Ex').checked;
                var checkedResVG = document.getElementById('Res-VG').checked;
                var checkedResGd = document.getElementById('Res-Gd').checked;
                var checkedResAve = document.getElementById('Res-Ave').checked;
                var checkedResPoor = document.getElementById('Res-Poor').checked;

                if (checkedResEx == false && checkedResVG == false && checkedResGd == false && checkedResAve == false && checkedResPoor == false) 
                {
                                     alert('You need to select a rating for Resiliance');
                                     return false;
                }
                else 
                {
                                     return true;

                }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isOneChecked() {
     var checkedResEx = document.getElementById('Res-Ex').checked;
     var checkedResVG = document.getElementById('Res-VG').checked;
     var checkedResGd = document.getElementById('Res-Gd').checked;
     var checkedResAve = document.getElementById('Res-Ave').checked;
     var checkedResPoor = document.getElementById('Res-Poor').checked;

     return (checkedResEx || checkedResVG || checkedResGd || checkedResAve || checkedResPoor);
 }
```

This will return true if at least one of the checkboxes is checked.

Comment: They are radio buttons and not checkboxes, so they can never all be checked. Each row can only have 1 radio button checked at any one time, but I need the form to validate that at least 1 option is selected for each row.

Comment: Thanks, but this still will not do what I am after. How can I get it to check each of the groups for at least one option being checked. So, Independent Thinking must have a selection AND Resilience must have a selection AND etc etc . The form cannot submit until all groups have at least one category selected.

Comment: Give both functions a different name like `independentThinkingChecked()` and `resilienceChecked()` and make a third function to check both of those:
`function areBothChecked() {
  return independentThinkingChecked() && resilienceChecked()
}`
Above will only return true if both those functions return true (checkbox checked in each one). Does it make sense?

Comment: This method is not working either. I have noticed it is submitting without anything checked at all so there is something quite wrong.